# How to add canvas confetti in snap.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, snap.svg

1. How to add **canvas confetti** in **snap.js** between g0 and g1

```
var s = Snap("#svg");
var down4 = s.polyline ('48.3,153.5 104.8,120.4 104.8,64.4 48.3,97.5').attr({'fill': '#7F1900'});
var down3_1 = s.polyline ('161.3,148.8 104.8,120.4 104.8,64.4 161.2,93').attr({'fill': '#7F1900'});
var down3 = s.polyline ('100.8,183.8 48.3,153.5 104.8,120.4 161.3,148.8').attr({'fill': '#590D00'});
var g0 = s.group(down3,down3_1,down4);

var down1 = s.path ('M48.3,97.5v56l52.5,30.3v-56.1h-0.1L48.3,97.5L48.3,97.5z').attr({'fill': gradientA});
var down2 = s.path ('M100.8,127.7v56.1l60.5-35v-56L100.8,127.7z').attr({'fill': gradientA});
var g1 = s.group(down1,down2);
```

```
confetti({
  particleCount: 100,
  startVelocity: 30,
  spread: 360,
  origin: {
    x: Math.random(),
    y: Math.random() - 0.2
  }
}
```

I haven't set up the coordinates yet. I took an example **canvas confetti**

2. animation on mouseover

```
var mouseoverFunc = function () {
 ? confetti() ?
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is given in the Russian version of the site. Answer on this [button](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1262629/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B8canvas-%D1%81-snap-js)